# Create Models from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Is there some way to generate **models from database** in Laravel?

The generators package only create an empty model.

Comment: What more are you expecting to be generated within the model file?

Comment: @Bogdan Because not all system use code first, sometimes need to use database first. That's crazy how biggest framework like Laravel doesn't support Database first officially.

Comment: @Bcktr while Laravel (or Django) is best suited for developing new applications, it’s quite possible to integrate it into legacy databases

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is a library [Eloquent Model Generator](https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator) which aim is creating Eloquent models classes using database tables as a source. It generates not only class stub, but relation methods, docblocks for magic fields, additional properties etc.

It provides a console command `php artisan krlove:generate:model ClassName` for generating one class per one call, but you can create your own command to call this command for each table from your database.

Comment: " but you can create your own command to call this command for each table from your database": https://github.com/krlove/eloquent-model-generator/issues/38#issuecomment-431660047

Answer (score 82):

**Warning, you may end up overwriting your JetStream or any other scaffolding models. take backup of them before overwriting them.**

If you are using MySQL and Laravel 5.1 or above you can use `php artisan code:models` from this package: [reliese/laravel](https://github.com/reliese/laravel). All you need to do is:

1. `composer require reliese/laravel`
2. Add the service provider to your `config/app.php` file `Reliese\Coders\CodersServiceProvider::class`
3. Publish the config file with `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=reliese-models`
4. Make sure your database is correctly configured in `config/database.php` and `.env` files.
5. And finally issue the command: `php artisan code:models`

This package will scan your database and create all models for you. If you need something more specific, you can customize its config file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The last command does no longer work with Laravel 5.6(.25): `There are no commands defined in the "code" namespace.`

Comment: Found it myself on documentation page:  https://github.com/reliese/laravel/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Though this answer helped me generate model classes from my tables, the issue is that these classes do not include public properties for table columns. Thus I do not get any auto-completion benefits in the IDE (VSCode).

Comment: Laravel (Eloquent) Models do not have public properties for table columns. These generated clases are Eloquent Models. In spirit of helping autocompletion I've added annotations to each generated class which some IDEs such as PhpStorm do use for autocompletion.

Comment: most likely you _don't_ want to redo _all_ your models each time... what most people probably are looking for is to do a single table (for lets say, you just added the table `users` and need a model for it): `php artisan code:models --table=users`

Comment: I have updated the reliese package to include PostgreSql... it can be found at https://github.com/rwdim/laravel . The original author is a genius, but he's not merging things with any speed at all.

Comment: You should use `php artisan config:clear` before `php artisan code:models`. It'll solve the problem of  *ErrorException 
mkdir(): Invalid path*

Answer (score 7):

Below package could be used for creating reverse models from database

```
composer require laracademy/generators
```

Please find the Documentation here -> https://github.com/laracademy/generators

Comment: Packate details please, Pros/Cons, documentation, github repository?? do not suggest to use something without supporting documentation.

Comment: `https://github.com/laracademy/generators` @jgarcias