# Is there any possible way to generate database from models in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Is there any possible way to generate database from models in Laravel ?
I am working on an existing laravel project,it contains models without their migrations.

I tried the reliese/laravel also the doctrine but nothing won't work ..any help ?

Comment: Hi Hajer! Apologies, we may need a bit more information, what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Usually you will create a model, and then a migration which will create your database tables

Comment: @CodeBoyCode i am working at an existing laravel project .. there's no migration that contains the tables of the database ..there are only models .

Comment: Is there anything within the database folder?

Comment: Doctrine **will** work but not with laravel models. Laravel takes a strict approach of migrations to update the database structure so if you want the doctrine approach you need to write doctrine models. Laravel models have no actual structure definition contained inside them

Comment: @HajerAmara, I hope, the answers of the below question may help you to proceed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158766/laravel-generate-database-from-model

Comment: @CodeBoyCode it cotains the factory , migrations and seeds. the factory contains ModelFactory , migrations contains only the two default tables create users table and create password reset table .

Comment: @GanesaVijayakumar i saw it but it did not help me :(

Comment: you may need to set up new migrations in this case - in the command line you would need to use for each of the models - php artisan make:migration create_modelname_table

Comment: @CodeBoyCode it will create an empty table , I don't know the columns of each table that's the probleme ..how whould I know wich is the primary key or the foreign key or the names of the columns

Comment: that is true - it will be very difficult to do it without those migration files - the only thing i can think of is if they are included within the $protected_fillable array within the model - but that won't include every column

Comment: @CodeBoyCode In my case not every model contains $protected_fillable and like you said it won't include every column also ..thx alot :)

Comment: @CodeBoyCode do you have any idea about diagram generator in Laravel ? i tried it but it didn't work . I wanted to generate the diagram so i can know the column of the tables but it didn't work

Comment: no sorry - i have never used it. It might be worth starting another question tagged with that and hopefully someone can help you with it :)

Comment: @CodeBoyCode okay thx =D

Comment: Good luck! I hope you solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have model `User`without migration then you can get table name from it like

`User::getTableName();` there is same function to get column names and you can get column types from `protected $cast = []`

Here is Sample code

```
        $location = new LocationTable(); // load your model
        $tableName = $location->getTable(); // this will give a table name from your model
        $columnsWithType = $location->getCasts(); // set all your table fields as cast

        Schema::create(tableName , function (Blueprint $table) use ($columnsWithType) {
            foreach ($columnsWithType as $columnName => $type) {
                $table->$type($columnName);
            }
        });
```

Comment: those lines I put them  in my Model ?

Comment: if you want to write migration for users table, then into that migration you put this line to get table name `User::getTableName()` and find columns and its types too