# How can if fix this Laravel one to many with a custom foreign key behavior

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, php-8, php-8.2

I'm new to laravel and trying to make two tables with a one (customer) to many(table) relation and a custom Foreign Key `tables`.`customer`(I can not change this)

The connection is over `customers`.`id` on `tables`.`customer`.

After Running `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` everything is created as expected. But `tables`.`customer` is always 0.
I don't get any errors. And both tables are created correctly.
What do I miss?

### Here are my settings:

**Models:**

Customers.php

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customers extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

  public function tables() {
    return $this->hasMany(Tables::class, 'customer');
  }

  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Tables.php

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tables extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

  public function customers() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class, 'customer');
  }

  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**Migration:**

customers

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up() {
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('id', 6)->primary();
      $table
        ->string('img', 23)
        ->nullable()
        ->default(null);
      $table->tinyText('name');
      $table->tinyInteger('active')->default(1);
      $table->bigInteger('created'); // unix timestamp when created
      $table
        ->bigInteger('status')
        ->nullable()
        ->default(null); // null not deleted / unix timestamp when deleted
    });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function down() {
    Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
  }
};
```

tables

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function up() {
    Schema::create('tables', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('id', 8)->primary();
      $table->tinyText('number');
      $table->string('customer', 6); // TODO: repalce with uuid
      $table->bigInteger('created'); // unix timestamp when created
      $table
        ->bigInteger('status')
        ->nullable()
        ->default(null); // null not deleted / unix timestamp when deleted
    });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function down() {
    Schema::dropIfExists('tables');
  }
};
```

**Factories:**

CustomersFactory.php

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Customers>
 */
class CustomersFactory extends Factory {
  /**
   * Define the model's default state.
   *
   * @return array<string, mixed>
   */
  public function definition() {
    return [
      'id' => $this->faker->unique()->regexify('[A-Za-z0-9]{6}'),
      'name' => $this->faker->company(),
      'active' => $this->faker->boolean(),
      'created' => $this->faker->unixTime(),
      'status' => $this->faker->boolean() ? null : $this->faker->unixTime(),
    ];
  }
}
```

TablesFactory.php

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Customers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Tables>
 */
class TablesFactory extends Factory {
  /**
   * Define the model's default state.
   *
   * @return array<string, mixed>
   */
  public function definition() {
    return [
      'id' => $this->faker->unique()->regexify('[A-Za-z0-9]{8}'),
      'number' => $this->faker->unique()->numberBetween(1, 1000),
      'customer' => Customers::factory()->create()->id,
      'created' => $this->faker->unixTime(),
      'status' => $this->faker->boolean() ? null : $this->faker->unixTime(),
    ];
  }
}
```

**Seeders:**

customersSeeder.php

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Customers;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CustomersSeeder extends Seeder {
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run() {
    Customers::factory()
      ->count(10)
      ->hasTables(20)
      ->create();
  }
}
```

TablesSeeder.php

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Tables;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TablesSeeder extends Seeder {
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run() {
    //
  }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```php
namespace Database\Seeders;

// use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {
  /**
   * Seed the application's database.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run() {
    $this->call([CustomersSeeder::class]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any errors, what is the issue? You run the seed and you get nothing created only on the `table` table?

Comment: tables.customer who should match with the created customers.id is allways 0 instead of the randomString id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you did not tell each model that the `id` is not an integer, it is by default (check the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8209afde1d14d4342ecb1457b7e6ee2ce51caee1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L63)).

So add this to both models:

```php
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

Read about that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys).

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting your models, you are recommended to define the table name first.

```
// ========== SPECIFY TABLE TO USE (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746287/19250775) ========== //
protected $table = "users";
```

And then you need to define fillable properties in order to mass assign your database, as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) said.

```
// ========== MASS ASSIGNABLE ATTRIBUTES ========== //
protected $fillable = 
[
    'id',
    'name',
    'email',
];
```

Or if you want every column becomes fillable just add guarded attribute.

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Comment: The order of methods and properties does not matter, and using fillables or not, should not matter as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#overriding-attributes) states that the Mass Assignment Protection (hence `$fillable` or `$guarded`) is turned off when using factories, but they could be wrong, I cannot recall now if that is the case or not

Comment: Ah, i don't see that faker creates non-integer primary key. Props to you :)